# Open UIImage from photo library with data

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, photo, nsdata

I have two view controllers, in one I pick the image from the photo library and assign it to an image property. With this picker:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo
```

But instead I would like to just get the address/data of the image from the picker in the first controller, push the next view controller and then open the image with that address there. So then I do the following:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

When I print info of the photo it looks something like this:

assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=52219875-C221-4F60-B9D4-984AAADB6E63&ext=JPG

The problem is that UIImage has methods `initWithData` or `imageWithData` but these accept NSData and not NSDictionary.

How can I open an image from a photo library using its data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img 
                  editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo
```

shouldn't be used, it's been deprecated since ios3

This method:

```
  - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

returns a dictionary, as you report.

The image pointer is one of the objects in this dictionary. You obtain it as such:

```
  UIImage* image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

Comment: He doesn't want the image, he asked for the URL, which should be used in a different view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate) for that method.

Basically there are a few keys in that dictionary, listen [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate):

```
NSString *const UIImagePickerControllerMediaType;
NSString *const UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage;
NSString *const UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage;
NSString *const UIImagePickerControllerCropRect;
NSString *const UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL;
NSString *const UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL;
NSString *const UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata;
```

You probably want `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage`. So this is what you're looking for:

```
UIImage *theImage = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
```

Of course you can get other info from the image with the other keys in the dictionary too.

Comment: Not, what he's looking for. He wants to pass the address, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary provides the URL for the image.
So load the data by

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[info valueForKey: UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]];
```

and use this data for the `NSImage initWithData` method.